# How do I store a simple variable in registry with Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a really simple question:

I want to store two user-entered variable strings in the registry and be able to access it later when the batch runs again. I have been googling for a while and can't seem to find the answer.

It can be stored in any registry as long as it will be available on next execution.

Here is the flow of what needs to happen:

```
:: Check if variable_a/b is available in reg, else ask user....?
SET /p variable_a="Enter a string: "
SET /p variable_b="Enter a string: "

:: Store both vars somehow....?

echo My variables:
echo variable_a
echo variable_b
```

Can you please help me solve this simple problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setx variable_a "%variable_a%"
setx variable_b "%variable_b%"
```

will simply store variables - such that any future CMD.EXE invocations in the same session will load the variables/values into the environment.

Add `/m` to save for the next and future logon(s) (not stored for THIS logon session)

```
setx variable_a ""
```

to delete - same rules.

Comment: So if I want to save it for this session and next logons I would have to use `setx variable_a "%variable_a%"` and `setx variable_a "%variable_a%" \m` directly after each other?

Comment: Yes - except that it's `/m` not `\m`

Comment: Oh, and can you please indicate how I can check if it exists?

Comment: `if defined variable_a` - what `setx` does is write a new value for the environment variable mentioned to the registry. Any `CMD.exe`(or, presumably, lesser programs) which is initiated after the `setx` was executed but within the same logon session will have `variable_a` set in its environment. The `/m` switch acts substantially in the same way - but on the NEXT logon session and NOT on this one.

Answer (score 0):

basetx is not available in all windows-versions.

Also, I would prefer storing the variables in a file, not in the registry

```
if not exist somepath\myvar.bat (
 SET /p varA="Enter a string: " 
 SET /p varB="Enter b string: "
 echo REM this is my permanent store >somepath\myvar.bat
 echo set variable_a=%varA% >> somepath\myvar.bat
 echo set variable_b=%varB% >> somepath\myvar.bat
)
call somepath\myvar.bat
```